# Famo.us grunt serve gives blank browser

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator, famo.us

Trying to start playing with the Famo.us example. I followed the steps on the Github page and when I do "grunt serve" the browser opens up but with the following errors:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    http://localhost:1337/lib/famous-polyfills/functionPrototypeBind.js
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
    http://localhost:1337/lib/famous-polyfills/classList.js
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
    http://localhost:1337/lib/famous/core/famous.css
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    
    http://localhost:1337/lib/famous-polyfills/requestAnimationFrame.js
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   
    http://localhost:1337/lib/requirejs/require.js
```

Running it on Windows 7 with Chrome. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do those files actually exist in your app directory?

Comment: Hi, no I can't find them anywhere. The only javascript files in the app folder are main.js and requireConfig.js. I didn't change anything just followed these steps: 
npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower generator-famous

mkdir newProject

cd newProject

yo famous

grunt serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment.. If those files do not exist, you need to make them exist. It is strange the files were not created using the ToolBelt.

Just go to github and grab the files you are missing.

famous/core : https://github.com/Famous/core

famous-polyfills : https://github.com/Famous/polyfills

requirejs: https://github.com/Famous/examples/tree/master/src/lib

**** EDIT ****

The Author of this tool has submitted a better answer.. Please read TheAlphNerd's response.

Comment: Thanks, btw. do you know where I can find a bundled and minified version of  the famo.us library?

Comment: @doorman np.. and I haven't seen a minified version. I know you grab the file that's linked in the source for Famo.us University.. but I'm not exactly sure what that contains.

Comment: Try running bower install again, then grunt serve

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running "bower install"?  All of those dependencies should be installed by default via bower when you run 'yo famous', but I have seen some instances where it does not.

I would ignore the above advice about cloning via github, there are other dependencies including require.js and almond that would not be installed using that method

Also, as far as minified version is concerned... if you run the "grunt" command you will have a minified, cache busted version of all your dependencies roll for you via require.js / almond.  This is better than simply having a minified version of the library as it will only link in modules used.

FWIW I am the author of the tool :D

Comment: also had this exact problem.. when I ran yo famous, it would just sit at the end of the command after installing a bunch of stuff. I would then need to control-c to stop the process.  I then ran grunt serve and it would give me a blank page.  To fix this I ran bower install and it finally installed all the famous-polyfills etc.